# Flutter: How can I make leading icon space?

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I am trying to create a pop up menu. How can I make leading icon space? When I set `null`, the layout will be like the picture below. And when I try to set `IconButton`'s `icon` `null`, the menu can't be opened.

[image]

The code is like this.

```
       PopupMenuItem(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: null,
        title: Text(
          'Item3',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Palette.whiteDarken1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    PopupMenuItem(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.exit_to_app,
            color: Palette.whiteDarken1,
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Log In',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Palette.whiteDarken1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: try removing the leading and setting the text alignment center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a sizedbox with size as per your icon size for leading widget

Comment: Thanks it works well. But seems like setting `width` property doensn't affect anythig.